# Call an array value with a for loop

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I've found this code on Stack Overflow:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0

for /f %%G in ('dir *.jpg /b') do (
   set /a count+=1
   set fileName[!count!]=%%~G
)

set fileName
```

My objective is to call a single value, for example set `fileName[1]`, that returns a particular value of the array, but I wish I could take the value, identify the pathname length and modify the creation date between this code:

```
$(Get-Item foo.txt).creationtime=$(Get-Date "11/24/2015 06:00 am")
```

All these in a for loop that returns the same value of count (which was all my jpg files in the actual directory).
That's because I have to rename all my jpg files and collect the date by the name (they have all the format: IMG-20151228-WA0002) and modify the creation date.
Is this possibile?

Comment: Your title and question should IMO be: How to change a file's CreationTime based on a date contained in the file name in the pattern `IMG-20151228-WA0002.jpg` I suggest to use a PowerShell one liner for this `gci IMG-*-*.jpg|? BaseName -match 'IMG-(\d{8})-'|%{$_.CreationTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],'yyyyMMdd',$Null)}`

Comment: CMD doesn't actually support arrays. What you have there is not an array but a bunch of individual variables with peculiar-looking names. Some people here on SO seem to be very fond of this poor emulation for reasons I fail to understand, but my recommendation is to avoid it, particularly when you have a language at your disposal that actually does support data structures like arrays (PowerShell).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Just to complete your information, Batch files doesn't support numeric variables either: all variables contain strings. So what you have in the `count` variable is not a number, but a string with a peculiar behavior that simulates numeric operations via the `set /A` emulator command.

Comment: @Aacini And the `if` statement (when using numeric comparison operators). That emulation is built into CMD, though, not imposed by the user.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Your phrase _"imposed by the user"_ have no sense. CMD and any other programming facility (like PowerShell) provides _tools_ that any user may or may not use. There is no way to "impose" CMD to do things it is not capable to do. However, any user may use any programming language in a creative way that, as a matter of fact, is the key that boosts new and original developments. You can not impose users to not use CMD features in any way they wants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\25\SO_53471858.ps1
## create a dumy dummy file
"" >IMG-20151228-WA0002.jpg

## check datetime
gci IMG-*-*.jpg|select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime

## a variant of the one liner from comment without aliases
Get-ChildItem IMG-*-*.jpg |
  Where-Object BaseName -match 'IMG-(\d{8})-*' |
    ForEach-Object{
      $_.CreationTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],'yyyyMMdd',$Null)
    }

## check datetime
gci IMG-*-*.jpg|select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime
```

---

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\25\SO_53471858.ps1

Name                    CreationTime        LastWriteTime       LastAccessTime
----                    ------------        -------------       --------------
IMG-20151228-WA0002.jpg 2018-11-26 01:31:47 2018-11-26 01:38:34 2018-11-26 01:31:51
IMG-20151228-WA0002.jpg 2015-12-28 00:00:00 2018-11-26 01:38:34 2018-11-26 01:38:34
```